# listbox not showing all items windows phone 8.1

Tags: listbox, windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to populate a listbox using binding in windows phone 8.1. I can't see all of the items in the control.

XAML:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid.ChildrenTransitions>
        <TransitionCollection>
            <EntranceThemeTransition/>
        </TransitionCollection>
    </Grid.ChildrenTransitions>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!-- Title Panel -->
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Margin="19,0,0,0">
        <TextBlock Text="Application Name" Style="{ThemeResource HeaderTextBlockStyle}" CharacterSpacing="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemCharacterSpacing}"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" x:Name="ContentRoot" Margin="19,0,19,0">
        <ComboBox 
            x:Name="ComboBox1"
            ItemsSource="{Binding}"
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top" 
            SelectionChanged="ComboBox1_SelectionChanged"
            />

        <ListBox x:Name="ListBox1" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Height="1000">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding GameName}" Margin="2"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

I populate the listbox in code:

```
private ObservableCollection<Game> _Games = new ObservableCollection<Game>();
public StartPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.navigationHelper = new NavigationHelper(this);
    this.navigationHelper.LoadState += this.NavigationHelper_LoadState;
    this.navigationHelper.SaveState += this.NavigationHelper_SaveState;

    ListBox1.DataContext = _Games;
}
....
private async void ComboBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var group = _Groups[ComboBox1.SelectedIndex];
    games = await DataServer.GetGamesAsync(group.GroupName);
    _Games.Clear();

    foreach (var game in games.OrderBy(g => g.GameName))
    {
       _Games.Add(game);
    }
}
```

There are 69 games but I can only see about 28 in the list view in the emulator when I scroll the list. It's clear that there are more items in the list, but I can't scroll to them. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Get rid of that Height=1000, does it show it all now?

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `StackPanel` with a `Grid` and add a couple more `RowDefinitions` in the second Grid you'll add. `StackPanels` don't size themselves dynamically, so instead of sizing to the screen, it's just stretched infinitely to the bottom.